# Javascript Image Toolbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, toolbox

I want to know if there is a jquery or javascript plugin that allows you to add an element into a div and move it across it and resize it (just like you would in photoshop).

I have to make a business card editor and I'm looking for a easy way out (and no flash).

Answer (score -1):

hey ciprian theres plenty of ways to move and resize divs in divs but if you are doing more graphics on to of that theres a good graphics lib: http://raphaeljs.com/

witch has drag and drop and all resize and transform functions you would expect.

then theres http://jqueryui.com/demos/ to witch has draggle and resizable.

Comment: I know all of this. But I'm looking for a plugin that will add the bounding box (dotted) as well as the resize small boxes (just like photoshop transform). I'm not actually interested in rotating.

Comment: you can have that done with these ones. if you are locking for a one liner i dont know of one. i would use raphael for this.

Comment: I already knew how to make one. I just needed one that was pre-made.

Comment: same here lokking for a "pre made" php/js image toolbox